# Codeacademy JavaScript - Section 2-1

Tags: javascript

I took an AP computer science course a few years ago, I learned Java from it. I'm trying this Codeacademy now and I'm puzzled by this one question, can anyone explain this to me?
Here is the question:

You are a creature of habit. Every week you buy 5 oranges. But orange prices keep changing!

1. You want to declare a function that calculates the cost of buying 5 oranges.
2. You then want to calculate the cost of the 5 all together.
3. Write a function that does this called orangeCost().
4. It should take a parameter that is the cost of an orange, and multiply it by 5.
5. It should log the result of the multiplication to the console.
6. Call the function where oranges each cost 5 dollars.

Here's my code:

```
var getCost = orangeCost (costOfOrange) {
    console.log(costOfOrange * 5);
};
getCost(5);
```

I believe it follows the syntax showed in earlier problems, but I'm getting this output:

```
SyntaxError: missing  before statement
Oops, try again. 
It looks like your syntax isn't quite right. 
Feel free to peek back at earlier exercises if you need help!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function definition in JavaScript can take one of two major forms:

```
function funcName(param1, param2, ...) { }
```

Or

```
funcName = function(param1, param2, ...) { }
```

Your example doesn't follow either. You probably want:

```
orangeCost = function(costOfOrange) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as simple as you forgot the `function` keyword and there's no orangeCost after the `=`:

```
var getCost = function (costOfOrange) {
    console.log(costOfOrange * 5);
};
getCost(5);
```

Did this help much?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved mine using the following code:

```
var orangeCost = function (price) {
    console.log(price * 5);
};
orangeCost(5);
```

I believe it was asking to verify that the orangeCost be the function name, that's why it refuses any other thing though there's other ways to do this. Hope this helps as I was also surprised by this question and spend sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var orangeCost = function (price) {

    console.log(price * 5);
}

orangeCost(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var orangeCost = function (price) {
    console.log (price * 5);
};

orangeCost(5);
```

You shoud call orangeCost value instead of "price" which is the function name.
there it goes.

Comment: This code may help but it would be much more useful if there was also an explanation of how this code answers the users question

Answer (score 0):

```
var orangeCost = function(price){
    var val = price*5;
    console.log(val);
}
orangeCost(7)
```

here is my code 
you could refer it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check it out dude. What you have done is that you are using orangeCost in place of function keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should have done:

```
var orangeCost = function(price) {
    console.log(price * 5);
}

orangeCost(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction below:

```
var  functionName = function(parameterName){
//function definition.what you want to do 
}
```

In your case the code may be like this:

```
var orangeCost = function(price)
{
    console.log(price*5);
}
orangeCost(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

easy.
Just create the function and evaluate it when printing out

```
var orangeCost = function (cost){
    console.log(cost * 5)
}

orangeCost(5);
```